# How to log the AWS Amplify API.get request to view queryStringParameters on url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, aws-amplify

I'm not sure how to log / see the actual request that is being made.

I can look at this code below and assume that it's `http://myendpoint.com?my/path?param=value`, however with more complex code and variables in other places, how can I tell what exactly is getting called via `API.get`?

The main reason I ask is because I don't think my query parameters are being appended to my request, and I'm hoping to confirm.

```
const apiName = 'http://myendpoint.com'
const path = '/my/path'
const myInit = {
    queryStringParameters: {
        param: 'value'
    }
}

API.get(apiName, path, myInit)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('> > > PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO LOG THE REQUEST < < <')
        resolve(response)
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('err resp', err)
        resolve(err)
    })
```

Edit: FYI this is in a REACT NATIVE project, so things like the Chrome Network tab are of no use unfortunately.

Comment: Well you could use something like the Network tab in Chrome's Dev Tools and see just about anything you want to see for that request.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. I am in a react native project, so not using a browser. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Not related to the question, but if anyone finds this - as of the time of my writing, the `queryStringParameters` object is not supported. In order to add params to the string you need to add them in the `path` argument. See https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/127 for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I actually think I figured this out, and it boiled down to two different things:

**1. ADDING THE AMPLIFY LOGGER:**

I found there is an Amplify logger via:
https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/logger_guide.md

So I added:

```
Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
```

and now when I am debugging in VS Code I'm seeing the request URL being logged.

**2. REALIZING 'queryStringParameters' ISN'T ACTUALLY SUPPORTED:** .

I was looking through the Amplify GitHub repo issues and found out that `queryStringParameters` isn't actually supported yet, which is fun.

URL to issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/127 .

So instead I appended all my query parameters onto the `path`, and that works:

```
const apiName = 'http://myendpoint.com'
const path = `/my/path?param=${value}`

API.get(apiName, path)
.then((response) => {
    resolve(response)
},
(err) => {
    console.log('err resp', err)
    resolve(err)
})
```

I am now seeing the request URL logged, and seeing the parameters as a part of the request.